Problems working with vector layers in R terra "Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring "
in the last weeks I got inconsistent results using vector layers in R using the terra package.
For example, using this dataset: http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/pwessel/gshhg/gshhg-shp-2.3.7.zip
A month ago I performed these actions (I used GSHHS_f_L1.shp but this problem happened with several layers in the zip file):
library(terra)
xx<-vect('~/GSHHS_f_L1.shp')
plot(xx)
is.valid(xx)
TRUE

The plot and everything else worked fine

One week ago I did it again using the same layer. The plot worked fine, but
is.valid(xx)
FALSE

yy<-makeValid(xx)
is.valid(yy)
TRUE

and again, everything worked fine.
However, the last days I got this error (same layer) that I still can't solved
is.valid(xx)
Error: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring

yy<-makeValid(xx)
Error: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring

After this, the plot is the only action that works. I try the common solution of creating a 0-buffer, but I got the same error.
I updated terra and downloaded the zip file again, but nothing change.
I know of some alternatives using sf, but I feel very comfortable with terra and I want to know if there is a solution using this package.
I'm using R 4.4.0, terra 1.7.78 in a laptop Linux Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. The only change in the last weeks was that I installed the package gower from github.
Any recommendation will be very appreciated

Can't see any obvious component of gower that would interfere with terra objects. Could not replicate the issue on Win10 machine with terra_1.7-78 and R R 4.4.0. Running is.valid(xx) returned a binary vector as expected. There is a single polygon with invalid geometry, off the coast of Maine, US.

On my Win10 machine, I found something weird going on with the data (or perhaps it is a bug?) that occurred when applying an sf solution, but not when using only terra. When I applied terra::makeValid() to the entire dataset, it worked. However, the equivalent sf::st_make_valid() did not work on the full dataset. I have added a potential terra-only workaround inspired by the sf issue that will hopefully work for you on your machine. I have also included the sf option by way of illustration, mainly to highlight the weird behaviour, which may be indicative of the issue you face.
First, using only terra:
library(terra)

# Load data
xx <- vect('~/GSHHS_f_L1.shp')

# Check validity
unique(is.valid(xx))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE

# Return valid
xx_is <- xx[is.valid(xx)]

unique(is.valid(xx_is))
# [1] TRUE

# Return invalid
xx_not <- xx[!is.valid(xx)]

is.valid(xx_not)
# [1] FALSE

# Make valid
xx_is1 <- makeValid(xx_not)

is.valid(xx_is1)
# [1] TRUE

# Recreate xx
xx <- vect(c(xx_is, xx_is1))

unique(is.valid(xx))
# [1] TRUE

Using sf:
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

xx <- vect('~/GSHHS_f_L1.shp')

# xx SpatVector to sf
xx_sf <- st_as_sf(xx) %>%
  st_make_valid() %>% # Does not work, but subsequent steps do not work without it either
  mutate(valid = st_is_valid(.))

# Check for invalid geometries (should not return any FALSE but does for some reason)
unique(st_is_valid(xx_sf))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE

# Return invalid polygon
not_valid <- filter(xx_sf, !valid)

st_is_valid(not_valid)
# [1] FALSE

# Make valid
is_valid <- st_make_valid(not_valid)

st_is_valid(is_valid)
# [1] TRUE

# Find index of oringinal invalid polygon
intersects <- st_intersects(is_valid, xx_sf)
# Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate was
# `intersects'
#  1: 2245

# Return invalid polygon
xx_sf_inv <- xx_sf[2245,]

xx_sf_inv
# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 7 fields
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -69.78281 ymin: 43.75223 xmax: -69.70734 ymax: 43.88222
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# id level source parent_id sibling_id     area                       geometry valid
# 2245 2380     1    WVS        -1         -1 45.04373 MULTIPOLYGON (((-69.76185 4... FALSE

# Filter out invalid polygon from xx_sf
xx_sf <- filter(xx_sf, id != 2380)

# Add valid version of polygon back to xx_sf
xx_sf <- rbind(xx_sf, is_valid)

# Recheck geometries
unique(st_is_valid(xx_sf))
# [1] TRUE

# Convert back to SpatVector
xx <- vect(xx_sf)

# Recheck geometries again
unique(is.valid(xx))
# [1] TRUE


Thank you so much. Option 1 in terra solve the problem.

@user3369539 - This was a real curious error. I'm convinced the issue I identified using sf is the same as the one you encountered using terra. For some unknown reason, it manifest differently, maybe because of different R environments? I've had 'foibles' like this before where previously working scenarios started throwing errors. As in your case, I suspect that up until those errors occurred, I was just 'lucky'. In other words, something stopped the error being caught. Either way, glad a solution was found.
